# Diagram tool stopped working in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL Server 2008 installed on my machine and use SSMS to manage remote 2008 and 2000 databases.  I recently tried to create a diagram on a local instance of SQL and get this error "Unspecified error (MS Visual Database Tools).  I have VS 2010 and APEXSQL tools installed.  I finally gave up and reloaded Windows 7 and all the dev tools and it worked for a day them started giving me this error again.

[image]

Where I click on details this is what I get:

> ===================================
>
> Unspecified error  (MS Visual Database Tools)
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.NativeMethods.ThrowOnFailure(Int32
>   hr)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn
>   origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions,
>   IManagedConnection con, String fileName)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VirtualProject.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ISqlVirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn
>   origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions,
>   IManagedConnection con, String fileName)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ISqlVirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn
>   origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions,
>   IManagedConnection con, String fileName)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptFactory.CreateDesigner(DocumentType
>   editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, Urn parentUrn,
>   IManagedConnection mc, String fileName)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.CreateDesignerWindow(IManagedConnection
>   mc, DocumentOptions options)

Comment: Any errors showing up in the Application Event log?  Does this same problem happen if you try it on a different database?  Does it happen on other machines?

Comment: I have occasionally found that SQL Enterprise manager "loses" certain features unexpectedly.  The solution, in general, seems to be uninstalling SQL Enterprise Manager desktop tools and reinstalling them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did some more research.  The guy in [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/d169c1bf-d7c6-4d30-8f6c-d04d3e8645b1/) said that he was having the same problem and ApexSQL Tools was the culprit.  Try uninstalling ApexSQL Tools, and if that resolves the issue, I'd be contacting ApexSQL to see if they have a fix for the problem.

Comment: It turns out that it is a bug in the APEXSQL Complete tool and they will fix the problem in their next release.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check compatability level of the database you were accessing ?
greetings jaco